# How to run an inline shell script from python?

Tags: python, bash

I have a small shell script in a string inside my python file.
Now I'd like to run this script via `subprocess.call()` and I wonder what's the best way.

My first thought was to write the script to a `StringIO` and specify that via `stdin=...` but unfortunately you cannot specify a `StringIO` since it doesn't have a `fileno()` method.

Of course I could use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and then write to it using `subprocess.communicate()` but I wonder if there's a simpler method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import subprocess

script = """
for x in 1 2 3 ; do echo $x ; sleep 1 ; done
"""

subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', script])
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I tried that before but apparently I failed at copy&paste and thus my bash script had an error.

Comment: for the record, `subprocess.Popen(['sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(script)` would also work, but you lose stdin.